# R Split a Vector to Overlapping Sub-Vectors and Conjoin the First and the Last Elements

Tags: r, split

I want to `split` a vector to follow these three(3) conditions using R:

1. Have an equal length of `l`
2. Overlap with a constant value `ov`
3. The first element and the last element alone of the parent vector should be for the last chunk (with just the two elements).

I got the below `R` code to meet the first two conditions as follows

```
ts = 1:10
l = 7
ov = l -1

library(tidyverse)
anil <- function(ts, l, ov){
  seq_len((length(ts) - ov) %/% (l - ov) +1) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames('id') %>%
    mutate(start = accumulate(id, ~ .x + l - ov),
           end = pmin(start + l - 1, length(ts)),
           start = pmin(start, end - l + 1)) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(paste(start, end, sep = '-'))) %>%
    transmute(desired = map2(start, end, ~ ts[.x:.y])) %>%
    as.list
}

anil(ts, l, ov)
```

I got this result:

```
>$desired[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

>$desired[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

>$desired[[3]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

>$desired[[4]]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I need help to meet the `third condition.

I want my result to look like this:

```
>$desired[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

>$desired[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

>$desired[[3]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

>$desired[[4]]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

>$desired[[5]]
[1]  1  10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append with the `range` of 'ts' in `summarise` before the `as.list`

```
anil <- function(ts, l, ov){
  seq_len((length(ts) - ov) %/% (l - ov) +1) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames('id') %>%
    mutate(start = accumulate(id, ~ .x + l - ov),
           end = pmin(start + l - 1, length(ts)),
           start = pmin(start, end - l + 1)) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(paste(start, end, sep = '-'))) %>%
    transmute(desired = map2(start, end, ~ ts[.x:.y])) %>%
    summarise(desired = c(desired, list(range(ts)))) %>%
    as.list
    
}
```

-testing

```
anil(ts, l, ov)
$desired
$desired[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

$desired[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$desired[[3]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

$desired[[4]]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$desired[[5]]
[1]  1 10
```

Comment: @DanielJames that is the R console sign.  Just copy and paste `anil(ts, l, ov)`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can use the following code with `embed` + `asplit` + `range`

```
c(
  asplit(embed(ts, l)[seq(1, length(ts) - l + 1, l - ov), l:1], 1),
  list(range(ts))
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

[[3]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[4]]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[5]]
[1]  1 10
```